# Where to keep ActiveMQ data?

Tags: tomcat, debian, tomcat6, activemq-classic

I'm managing server which runs tomcat6 with application, written by our programmers. It uses ActiveMQ. Application saves ActiveMQ queue data in $JAVA_TEMP/activemq-data. Tomcat6 on Debian Squeeze clears $JAVA_TEMP(/tmp/tomcat6-temp by default) on every restart. Programmers say, that this data must be persistent between service restart. What is proper place for java servlets to keep persistent data? IMHO it's not $JAVA_TEMP directory. Or may be programmers are right and I should change default Debian tomcat behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ provides persistence adaptors to store messages that are required over server restart. There are different strategies to persist messages.

- File based persistence store: In this strategy messages are stored on to file store. You can specify the directory in the ActiveMQ configuration. See the example below, for more details of configuration please refer: http://activemq.apache.org/amq-message-store.html

  `<broker brokerName="broker" persistent="true" useShutdownHook="false">`
  `<persistenceAdapter>`

  `<amqPersistenceAdapter directory="activemq-data" maxFileLength="32mb"/>`

  `</persistenceAdapter>`

  `<transportConnectors>`

  `<transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>`

  `</transportConnectors>`

  `</broker>`
- Database based persistence store: In this strategy messages are stored in database, use this if your messages are critical. For information on configuring JDBC - database persistence please refer http://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-support.html

Comment: Where directory="activemq-data" is placed in this configuration? In $JAVA_TEMP? What is proper way for jave servlets to store persistent files?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to storage for java servlets, scalability comes to mind. Usually, Java servlets are built and designed to be deployable at multiple servers (tomcat instances etc.) at once, for vertical scaling. Therefore a rule of thumbe is to use database storage whenever possible. In your specific case, you seem to run a single server, you could use any location on the file system you want. Perhaps you want to store the data on NAS/SAN.

ActiveMQ can cope with most storage options through the persistence adapters.

This [link](http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html) describes how ActiveMQ handles persistence and how to configure it. It's a rich domain and it dependes a lot of requirements and how you like to have things setup.